# how to update my applications iOS7?

Tags: updates, iphone-5, ios7, xcode5

I am a iOS developer.I have to update my old applications for iOS7.I developed my old apps in iOS6 and XCode4.Now, I try to execute iOS7 ,but doesn't work iOS7.How to compile and execute my old apps in iOS7.How to use XCode5?Do you know any idea?

Comment: seems like google would answer this...

Comment: ı cant see your answer@MitchWheat

Comment: I am googling too, but ı cant find answer.@MitchWheat

Answer (score 0):

When you open the storyboard of your application in XCode 5, this will automatically convert the old storyboard with the new one compatible with iOS 7. Then you have to change the old iOS 6 api with the new iOS 7 api.

All information for translate and optimize your old project (code and inteface) are here:

[https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/navigation/](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TransitionGuide/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013174)

[Apple Transition Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TransitionGuide/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013174)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I try it.I did always upgrades all xibs, but ıt didn't work.When I run the project in Xcode5, it through 'thread exception'. @Max_Power89

Comment: yes, project is build successfully.Launch image appears, but view_controller_xib doesn't open.I get thread exception. @Max_Power89